# Remove class on adding class to another element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a long list of image elements, each with it's own ID. I've already set it up so that when you click on one image, it will toggle a class "foo".
What I'd like to do is set it up so that when you click on another image, the first image's class "foo" will be removed. **I'd like to do this with pure javascript if possible.** Thanks.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3aRC/

```
function clicked($id) {
    document.getElementById($id).classList.toggle('foo');
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest, given that you're already using the `classList` api:

```
function clicked($id) {
    // get all the elements with the class-name of 'foo':
    var others = document.querySelectorAll('.foo');
    // if there *are* any elements with that class-name:
    if (others.length){
        // iterate through that collection, removing the class-name:
        for (var i = 0, len = others.length; i < len; i++){
            others[i].classList.remove('foo');
        }
    }
    /* add the class-name back (if it already had the class-name
       we removed it in the previous section): */
    document.getElementById($id).classList.add('foo');
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/K4WXc/2/).

References:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList).

Comment: +1. Nice. You don't really need the `if` test on the `length` though - is that worth doing when the `for` loop handles it anyway?

Comment: I honestly never gave it a thought; I just *expected* there to be a an error without the `if`...

Comment: Ah, fair enough. You know what they say: when you "expect" you just make an "ex" out of...um...your "pecs". Or something.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a common class to all images and remove the `foo` class from all of them. Then I would add the class to the specific image

```
function clicked(id){
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName('images');
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    images[i].classList.remove('foo');
  }

  document.getElementById(id).classList.add('foo');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately getElementsByClassName is not supported in ie8 and below

Comment: @DougAmos Yeah, if this would be for a current production environment, I would go with jQuery 99% of the time, but it seems that OP is doing this for toying and learning, so I assume this will be for latest browsers

Comment: @JuanGuerrero Yes. Just a summer project to make myself a portfolio page. I'm currently constantly changing/playing, but if you're intersted: esw8633.cias.rit.edu/portfolio

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using `classList` I assume you're only catering to browsers new enough for `addEventListener()`, so I'd suggest removing all of the `onclick` attributes and doing something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {
        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
            if (imgs[i] != e.target)
                imgs[i].classList.remove('foo');

        e.target.classList.toggle('foo');
    }
}, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q3aRC/3/

That is, bind a single click handler to the document (or you could bind to a parent element of the images if they share a common parent), and then on click test if the clicked item is one of the elements you care about (i.e., an img) and go from there... The JS ends up about the same length, but the html ends up shorter and neater. You could actually remove the `id` attribute too if you weren't using it for anything other than your original `clicked()` function.

I used `getElementsByTagName()` just to show you yet another way of doing it, but `getElementsByClassName()` or `querySelectorAll()` (as in the other answers) are probably better options. But that's an easy switch to make.

Comment: In my case, the individual elements are loaded with ajax and a php script, I had some trouble getting any javascript to work like that... and I don't know how to use it all that well

Comment: If the elements are loaded dynamically that makes the delegated event handler even better, because it will automatically work for elements added later. In case it's not obvious, it doesn't have to apply to _all_ img elements on the page, you can make the code more specific than that... Play around a bit with the fiddle I supplied.